# C# - Import reference project as DLL with configuration

Tags: c#

**Background**

I have an existing project ("Project A") which has config files set up as `JSON` files. It was implemented with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` package.

This existing project has a lot of useful functions and I do not want to rebuild them in my new project("Project B"). Hence I tried to add Project A to Project B as DLL file.

**Problem**

After adding the reference, it seems the configuration setup in Project B has become difficult to handle, things like DB connections etc. Those were configured in Project A and passed into functions in Project A using dependency injection. Basically the DLL does not read the configuration of Project B even though I tried the exactly same Json file structure.

**Question**

1. Is it recommended at all to add reference of Project A into Project B as DLL?
2. If yes, then how should I handle configurations like DB connections, and other parameters which Project A requires?

Comment: The configuration will be picked by only startup project or app which is running, so if your project B is the main project and project A is a class library(B referenced to A) then application will pick configuration from A's config file.

Comment: There are two ways to implement Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, One is write wrapper to use in project B or add this extension to B project directely.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to extend "Project A" and have things like your DB connection in "Project B" ported into "Project A". It seems like right now the system is checking the config in "Project A" only.